# Executing Jasmine via Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to run some Jasmine tests via Grunt from the command-line. To do that, I installed the `grunt-contrib-jasmine` package. Please note, this is not a web app. In an attempt to add a testing task I can execute from Grunt, I added the following in my gruntfile.js.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jasmine: {
    myTests: {
      src: "shared/modules/*.js",
      options: {
        specs: "shared/tests/unit/**.tests.js",
        vendor: "node_modules/**/*.js",
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs')
        }
      }
  }
});
```

My grunt task is configured like this:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
grunt.registerTask('myTests', [
    'jasmine:myTests'
]);
```

When I run `grunt myTests` from the command-line, I get a TON of errors. Yet all of the errors look like reference type errors. For instance, I see:

```
Error: notloaded: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module
Error: notloaded: Module name "retrypolicyfilter" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
...
```

My code works fine while running it in the context of Node.js. I want to create some unit tests to have a bit more coverage. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same issue and suspect that `grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs` simply does not work.